# how to apply style to complete row or table in tabulars

Tags: tables

How can I define a style (font, size, color etc) for a whole row, without repiting the command before each cell?

Note that I do not want to use tabu package. I want to know to what extent this can be done without tabu. (nothing against tabu, I want to demonstrate the usage of standard tabular env. and in contrast tabu).

Also I do not want to add new columntypes. The principle shall be applicable to any table in a complex document, without inventing columntypes for each column in each table.

This example shows that only the first cell after the setting of styles is changed.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[
  dvipsnames, % Load a set of predefined colors 
  table,      % Load the colortbl package
]{xcolor}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
%  --- table -->
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \centering
  \sffamily
  \rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{white!100}%
  % <------------
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
%  --- thead -->
\rowcolor{gray!25}
\small
\rmfamily
% <------------
   header &
   header &
   header \tabularnewline
\hline
%  --- tbody -->
\tiny\slshape
% <------------
content & content  & content \tabularnewline
content & content  & content \tabularnewline
content & content  & content \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're going to show good examples of LaTeX code, please refrain from using the `[H]` option for floating objects. In some occasions it can come handy, but in general it's not recommendable.

Comment: I need a group, because otherwise the commands after `\begin{table}` would be applied to the whole document. I would prefer to write `\begin{table}[float=none]` but that is not implemented. Since there is no other solution which combines this functionality with self explaining code I always use [H] if I do not want floats.

Comment: if you don't want floats, it's always possible to wrap the object to be isolated in `\begingroup ... \endgroup` which has nearly the same effect; the major difference of which i'm aware is that it doesn't include the extra vertical space associated with floats, but you can always add that yourself.

Comment: I know many ways to achieve the same. `\begingroup .. ` is one of them. But I prefer readable self-explanatory code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together I package which almost does what I want - configurable tables styles.
Here is an example of the user API. Please provide feedback if you like it or what should be changed. The full code including a very detailed example is linked below.

> [Table Style](http://code.google.com/p/latexthesistemplate/source/browse/#svn/trunk/packages/tablestyles)

```
\begin{table}[H]
\tablestyle[sansboldbw]
\captionabove{table with darker alternating colors}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{v{0.45\textwidth}}}
\theadstart
   \thead header &
   \thead header \tabularnewline
\tbody
\tsubheadrow{2}{subheader} 
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 %
 \tsubheadstart
 \tsubhead subhead &
 \tsubhead subhead \tabularnewline
 %
 content  & content \tabularnewline
 content  & content \tabularnewline
\tend
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The API for configuration of new styles can be improved. Documentation is not available currently. But I only want to start if the code itsself is considered useful. What I do not like currently is the definition of new columnstyles. But that is part of another thread.

Comment: Your links are dead ;)

Comment: I no longer work there... But the whole code is online at http://code.google.com/p/latexthesistemplate/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpackages%2Ftablestyles